# Is Partition key mandatory in the CRUD operations | cosmos db Java SDKv4

Tags: java, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am migrating from documentdb SDK to cosmosdb SDK v4.

I see below pattern in sync api methods

`createItem` -- has methods exposed with & without partition key as argument.

`upsertItem`-- has no way to pass partition key as argument.

`replaceItem` & `deleteItem` ---  1 method with partition key as argument.

**Keeping performance aside,**

1. Will all these methods work even without partition key ?
2. sending null is same as not sending partition key ? (With null, i thought cosmos might look for the null partition but in the case of `replaceItem` & `deleteItem` it is single exposed method with partition key as argument. Does that mean partition key is mandatory for `replaceItem` & `deleteItem` )

Not able to find any official doc confirmation. Any leads would be of great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It isn't mandatory to explicitly tell cosmos about the partition key (via  argument or CosmosItemRequestOptions) during a CRUD operation.
   If  unavailable, cosmos reads the document (which is being added/updated) and finds the partition key.
2. Sending partition key argument as null is same as not sending partition key.

   ```
   a. container.createItem(document, new PartitionKey(null), null); // cosmos looks for partition defined by null key
   b. container.createItem(document, null, null); //  scans document to figure out partition key value as stated in (1)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You declare a partition key while creating the collection. The object which you are passing to methods like "createItem" "upsertItem" will have a field with the property name matching the partition key declared during the collection creation. The value of that field will be used as the partition key value.

Example:

Collection partition key "/customerId"

Object to be Persisted:

```
    public class Order {
        private String id;
        private String status;
        private String customerId;
        private BigDecimal subTotal;
        private List<LineItem> lineItems = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Create Order:

```
    public Mono<Integer> createOrder(Order order) {
        return cosmosDB
                .getContainer()
                .createItem(order)
                .map(CosmosItemResponse::getStatusCode);
}
```

Gere you fund a full working example a store application that uses V4 java SDK.
https://github.com/RaviTella/store